# Are there intents for controlling Cyanogenmod profiles?

Tags: cyanogenmod, profiles, llama

I'd like to use Llama. Instead of its own profiles I want to keep using the ones provided by Cyanogenmod because of their better integration. Is Ist possible to change them using llama, ie are there any intents that make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two ways of doing this:

1. The intents used can be searched throughout the entire source of CM available on [github](https://github.com/CyanogenMod), notably `frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml` and general `grep` ping of the source.
2. `adb shell dumpsys | grep "Action: \"android.intent.action"`

The second option is the easiest - from AOSP here's a list of the intents... the mileage will vary slightly with CM as that would have extras or omissions:

```
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.WALLPAPER_CHANGED
android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW
android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY
android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED
android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED
android.intent.action.SYNC_STATE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG
android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_OK
android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
android.intent.action.TIME_SET
android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
android.intent.action.TIME_SET
android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE
android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT
android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED
android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED
android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE
android.intent.action.DATA_CONNECTION_FAILED
android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE
android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE
android.intent.action.DATA_CONNECTION_FAILED
android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_SHARED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNSHARED
android.intent.action.REBOOT
android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE
android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG
android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT
android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW
android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.RADIO_TECHNOLOGY
android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE
android.intent.action.EMERGENCY_CALLBACK_MODE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_OK
android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE
android.intent.action.DATA_CONNECTION_FAILED
android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE
android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT
android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
android.intent.action.TIME_SET
android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_FULL
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_NOT_FULL
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED
android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_OK
android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE
android.intent.action.DATA_CONNECTION_FAILED
android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE
android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT
android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
android.intent.action.SIG_STR
android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_OK
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_OK
android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS
android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON
android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART
android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE
android.intent.action.DATA_CONNECTION_FAILED
android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE
android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED
android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
android.intent.action.TIME_SET
android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED
android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG
android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
android.intent.action.TIME_SET
android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW
android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
android.intent.action.TIME_SET
android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.WALLPAPER_CHANGED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE
android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON
android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
android.intent.action.TIME_SET
android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
```

Comment: I looked through the Cyanogenmod list of intents and couldn't find anything suitable.

Comment: @Erik: Are you trying to change the profile used by CM, for example, changing to silent profile to deactivate sound/music/notifications? Am not sure if you can physically intercept the profile change as that's internal to CM, from looking at `frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ProfileManager.java` there is no intent broadcasted.

Comment: I don't need to listen to any broadcasted intents for this, do I? All I need to do is to send one. Of course it's very much possible that CM doesn't accept any, I will look into the source myself later.